# Javascript Won't Play Sound Based on New Entry To Database

Tags: javascript, php, xampp

I am using AJAX to long poll an Access database. Everything works perfectly so far, when a new entry is recorded the alert pops up to notify the user. However, no matter what I do, the sound won't play. I am not sure if this could be a possible reason, but my `wav` file is saved in the same folder in my `XAMPP/htdocs` folder.

```js
setInterval(function() {   
    var old_count = <?php echo $arr['counter']; ?>;
    var audio = new Audio('alert.wav');

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "dbcheck.php",
        timeout: 15000,
 
        success : function(data){
            if (data > old_count) {
                alert('New Hot Part Has Been Entered.');
                document.getElementById('audiotag1').play();
                old_count=data;
                location.reload();
            }

        }
    });
 
},5000);
```

```html
<audio id="audiotag1" src="alert.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `location.reload();` directly after the sound is started. I assume that the sound does not start fast enough to be hearable.

Try something like this:

```
if (data > old_count) {
    alert('New Hot Part Has Been Entered.');
    document.getElementById('audiotag1').play();
    old_count=data;

    window.setTimeout(function(){ 
        location.reload();
    }, 3000);

}
```